# Unminify CSS styles

Tags: css

I am trying to un-minify/un-merge my CSS styles. I have a style.css file with lots of merged styles in it, something like:

```
.style1,.style2,.style3{float: right}.style1{border-radius: 15px}.style2{border-radius: 0}.style3{border-radius: 10px}
```

What I am trying to convert it into is:

```
.style1{float: right;border-radius: 15px}
.style2{float: right;border-radius: 0}
.style3{float: right;border-radius: 10px}
```

How can I un-merge minified css styles to get such an output? I have tried several CSS Beautifiers and Unminifiers but they do not exactly what I need.

**UPD: Here is the solution: [codebeautifier.com](http://www.codebeautifier.com)**
. In order to get same output as in my example above, open this page, find  `Regroup selectors`, set it to `Only seperate selectors (split at ,)`, paste your CSS and hit `Process CSS`

Comment: Have you tried Prettier? It's a very good code beautifier that can be used programmatically. https://github.com/prettier/prettier

Comment: thanks, will give it a try. haven't heard of it before

Answer (score 2):

Try https://unminify.com/. Nothing to install, nothing to pay. Copy, paste, boom:

```css
.style1,
.style2,
.style3 {
    float: right
}

.style1 {
    border-radius: 15px
}

.style2 {
    border-radius: 0
}

.style3 {
    border-radius: 10px
}
```

Comment: This seems to just unminify the styles but not to sort them as in expected output

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Atom` text editor, you can use `atom-beautify` . The link to the package is https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify . That formats the code into well organized structure.

From your minified `css`, it formats it to look like this

```
.style1 {
   float: right;
   border-radius: 15px;
}
.style2 {
   float: right;
   border-radius: 0;
}
.style1 {
   float: right; 
   border-radius: 10px;
}
```

With that atom package, you can format other popular languages, such as `JavaScript`, `Python`, `Ruby`, `Swift`, etc.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thank you for your reply. I just installed Atom and the beautify package, but my result is the following: .style1, .style2, .style3 {
  float: right
}

.style1 {
  border-radius: 15px
}

.style2 {
  border-radius: 0
}

.style3 {
  border-radius: 10px
}. Same result is given by online beautifiers. Did you apply any settings to your Atom program to get your result?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I've forgot to tell you about that. After you install `Atom` and `atom-beautify`, in your `Atom` editor, you should see the menu. Now you need to search for `Preferences` option (Or just press `Ctrl + comma`). On Windows it's under `File`, and on Linux it's under `Edit`. When `settings` tab opens, you should see a menu on the left. Go to `Packages > Community Packages > atom beautify`. Click on `settings`. Find `CSS`. Click on it. Make sure that the default beautifier is `JS Beautify`, scroll down, check `Indent comments` & `Newline between rules`.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Vladimir. All my default `Atom Beautify` settings are same as yours. I updated them by disabling and re-enabling again, but it did not change the result, Atom still merges the selectors with identical parameters: https://image.prntscr.com/image/NthlRdTZRq_AgBOuqkL_zw.png

Comment: Your `printscreen` is showing me that the `atom-beautify` package is working correctly. It is suppose to format like that. If you have commas in your `css` file, the package will put them in one row (like the first line), if you have a single selector, the package will put them like block (like it is already). I don't think you will find a tool that will format your code in rows like in your question, because that is not nice to a human eye. The `atom-beautify` package does the good job, it has over 3 million downloads.

Comment: But answer down below from Stuart is giving you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat my.min.css | awk '{gsub(/{|}|;/,"&\n"); print}' >> my.css
```

Comment: Sorry, did not get it. Where does one put this code?

Comment: in a terminal session

Answer (score -1):

Prettify it in Sublime, use ctrl + Shift + P then install bundles then install prettify , use it. it works

Comment: It Doesn't regroup the style property

Answer (score -1):

Try out this tool: https://fixcode.org/minify/css

I ran your code in the css minifier and this is the result

```
.style1,
.style2,
.style3 {
   float: right
}
.style1 {
   border-radius: 15px
}

.style2 {
   border-radius: 0
}

.style3 {
   border-radius: 10px
}
```

Comment: this does not do what I asked originally. please see the expected output in my question