# Quick way to Order one line CSS files in Visual Studio

Tags: html, css

This days I have to support a project that have it's all css files written as one liners. Don't have to say it but it hell to read. I have ordered one by hand to do some work in it but there are more. Is there any tool that can order the files in tree like form. I think visual studio had such option but I don't seems to find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unminify CSS styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916091/unminify-css-styles)

Comment: Maybe you're looking to beautify the CSS? There are numerous online tools and extensions for various editors but I'm not sure about Visual Studio in particular.

Answer (score 0):

I Found it. No idea how did I miss it the firs time . 
Visual Studio - > Right Click in the Document -> Format Document. 
If you want to format only part select it Format Selection. No idea how I missed it I am a bit rusty I guess

Answer (score -1):

you can use some sandbox for make your code pretty. For example https://jsfiddle.net/ you shoud write your code in CSS box, and push button Tidy